# Adjust position: Fixed in Two different component of React

Tags: reactjs

Greetings all the way !

As in picture [image]
In Home Component i wrap the Container as:

```
"z-index": 1,
position: "fixed",
left: 0,
right: 0,
top: 0
```

and in App Component

```
<Header />
<Home />
```

then certain height of Home was overlapped with Header ! and yet i don't know the height of header ! its responsive to the width of screen ! I want to adjust the Home Component as height of Header.

extra question: How can i achieve header [like this](https://medium.com/) when scroll page in react .

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you do not rely on undetermined height of Header. Use some height (about 50px) and then you can set `margin-top: 50px` for the Home component.

Otherwise, you can use some third-party library:

- [react-sticky](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sticky).
- [react-sticky-header](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sticky-header)

I think they have what you need.